# How do I access a chunk blob data with ng-flow?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, azure-media-services, flow-js, ng-flow

I'm trying to access a chunk of blob data using ng-flow from an angular controller.

```
       $scope.$on('flow::fileAdded', function(event, $flow, flowFile) {

            console.log(flowFile.chunks[0]) // See image output from console

        });
```

[image]

I'm looking to pass the chunk blob object via a service call but no idea how to access it. I can't use ng-flow's built in upload methods since it's a special case using Azure WAMS so any help getting access to these chunks of data as blobs is much appreciated.

Comment: flow-init method and 'flow::fileAdded' should be in same controller

Comment: I don't understand? flow-init is in the html and this controller is assigned to this with ng-controller. I'm seeing the file, can access its properties, but not the chunked blob data.

Comment: can you please attach fiddle with problem or add your html code?